# How to convert a simple js code in react js.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passwords, state

Iam trying to generate random string in react js i have a javascript function for generating a random number but when i try to write it in react js it has started giving me error like length is not defined split is not defined what is the correct way to write it. i have tried doing it below you can see some part of the code converted in react basic aim is to set the state of password which is in my state object to the random string generated by the function.

```
  randomString = (len) => {
    let length = len ? len : 8;
    let string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //to upper
    let numeric = "0123456789";
    let punctuation = "!@$%^&*()_+~`|}{[]:;?><,./-=";
    let password = "";
    let character = "";
    let crunch = true;
    while (password.length < length) {
      let entity1 = Math.ceil(
        string.length * Math.random() * Math.random() + string
      );
      let entity2 = Math.ceil(numeric.length * Math.random() * Math.random());
      let entity3 = Math.ceil(
        punctuation.length * Math.random() * Math.random()
      );
      hold = string.charAt(entity1);
      hold = password.length % 2 == 0 ? hold.toUpperCase() : hold;
      character += hold;
      character += numeric.charAt(entity2);
      character += punctuation.charAt(entity3);
      password = character;
    }
    this.setState({
      password: password
        .split("")
        .sort(function () {
          return 0.5 - Math.random();
        })
        .join(""),
    });
    return password.substr(0, len);
  };
```

Comment: Nothing. Use that as a function. Just copy and paste it in the `App.js` or whatever file. For the error that occurs, you just need to post the full React code so we can look into it. Maybe you're not passing the `len` variable properly.

Comment: this is the full code len is used in this function only

Comment: Can you show where this problem happens in React please? Show your issue in https://CodeSandbox.io.